# Interpolação spline em python?

Tags: python

Qual o melhor método para fazer uma interpolação *spline* de segunda ordem em Python? Já utilizei o `interp1d`, mas não é bem o que pretendo.

Exemplo do que é pretendido.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = [5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
y = [2,9,6,3,4,20,6]


xx = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] 
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='quadratic') 
g = f(xx)
```

Pretendo calcular o `yy`, mas obtenho o seguinte erro:

> ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.

Gostaria de obter para python algo parecido com o seguinte em matlab

```
x=[5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
y=[2,9,6,3,4,20,6]
xx=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
yy = spline(x,y,xx);
plot(x,y,'o',xx,yy)
```

Comment: O código que executei encontrar-se na questão publicada.

Comment: Bom dia, o valor de xx esta acima do range de interpolação, se tu deixar de 5 a 11, vai rodar, porem não sei qual sua intenção de usar este range.